# Optimisation problem with a definite integral whose bounds are min of a set

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, nonlinear-optimization

What I am trying to do is finding an optimal $b_2$ for my objective function.
The objective function is an expected utility from two outcomes.
I denote the probability of outcome 1 as $P$ and that of outcome 2 as $1 - P$.
And this probability is from a multidimensional uniform distribution.
It is a marginal CDF.
But for simplicity, I set that only a variable of one dimension is deviating and the rest is parameter.
And other assumption is that all varibles are in the interval $(0, 1]$.

The problem is that bounds are the function of $b_2$.

The probability term is
$$
P(b_2) = \int\limits_{0}^{min\{1; x(b_2)\}} min\{1; y(b_2, h)\}f(h)dh.
$$
$x$ and $y$ are quadratic functions of $b_2$.
And I know for which value of $b_2$ bounds are bigger than 1.
For example, when $0.5 < b_2 < 0.7$, $x$ is strictly smaller than 1.

So what I am thinking is that

1. Set 4 cases of this probability based on whether a bound is bigger than 1 or not.
2. Get the probability maximising $b_2$ for each case.
3. See if $b_2$ is smaller than 1 and also fits in the range of $b_2$ like I mentioned above for an example.
4. When 3. is satisfied keep $b_2$ as an optimal value.
5. If not, abandon $b_2$ and the case where $b_2$ is derived from.

Is this is a correct step?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand your approach, possibly due to typos and/or a language barrier – for instance, I don’t know what you mean by “Set $4$ cases of this probability”. One thing that definitely seems wrong in your description is “See if $b_2$ is smaller than $1$”, which should probably be “$x(b_2)\lt1$”; I also suspect that where you say “maximizing $b_2$” you want to be maximizing $P(b_2)$.

In any case, the standard approach to this sort of problem would be to optimize separately for the two cases of the minimum, i.e. optimize $P(b_2)$ with respect to unrestricted $b_2$ with the upper limit of the integral taken as $1$, and the same with the upper limit taken as $x(b_2)$. If you find any optima, you can check for self-consistency, i.e., in the first case whether $x(b_2)\ge1$ and in the second case whether $x(b_2)\le1$. You then need to compare any self-consistent optima you find with the values on the boundary, $x(b_2)=1$, since $P(b_2)$ isn’t differentiable there so you wouldn’t find those by setting the derivative to zero.

Comment: I admit that I omitted a lot from my orginal model. Originally $x(a1, a2, b1, b2)$ and $y(a1, a2, b1, b2, h)$. $x$ is a critical value of dimension 1. And $y$ is a critical value of dimension 2. The support of this 2D model is $(0, 1]^2$. And the objective function is $$ EU_B = (1-P) \times u_B(b_2) + P \times u_B(a_2) $$. And what I want to do is maximising $EU_B$ w.r.t. $b_2 \in (0, 1]$. As I'm interested in $b_2$ for simplicity I set variables other than $b_2$ and $h$ to be parameters.

Comment: And by four cases what I meant is $$ \int\limits_{0}^{1} 1 \times f(h)dh$$, $$\int\limits_{0}^{1} y(b_2, h) \times f(h)dh$$, $$\int\limits_{0}^{x(b_2)} 1 \times f(h)dh$$, and $$\int\limits_{0}^{x(b_2)} y(b_2, h) \times f(h)dh$$. But I feel that your answer confirmed my thought process. I think I can just check "self-consistency" of $b_2$ value as you mentioned. Because I already have figured out for which range of $b_2$ value what probability term is realised. When the optima $b_2^*$ doesn't fit in that range, I can conclude that it doesn't hold.